# Sails 0.11 catching socket events from server side

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

As per the new release of sails v0.11, the function **onConnect** is deprecated in config/sockets.js file.
I couldn't implement the socket.on events or catch socket events from server side.
Is there any way to implement ?

working by updating code in `config/bootstrap.js` as @mikermcneil suggested:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) { 
    sails.io.on('connect', function (socket){
        socket.on('testE',  function(data)  {
            socket.emit('testEvent',{p1:'hehe'});
        });
    });
cb();
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out the migration guide here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/0.11-migration-guide.md#onconnect-lifecycle-callback

`onConnect` lifecycle callback

> **tldr;**
>
> Remove your `onConnect` function from `config/sockets.js`.

The `onConnect` lifecycle callback has been deprecated.  Instead, if you need to do something when a new socket is connected, send a request from the newly-connected client to do so.  The purpose of `onConnect` was always for optimizing performance (eliminating the need to do this initial extra round-trip with the server), yet its use can lead to confusion and race conditions. If you desperately need to eliminate the server roundtrip, you can bind a handler directly on `sails.io.on('connect', function (newlyConnectedSocket){})` in your bootstrap function (`config/bootstrap.js`). However, note that this is discouraged.  Unless you're facing *true* production performance issues, you should use the strategy mentioned above for your "on connection" logic (i.e. send an initial request from the client after the socket connects).  Socket requests are lightweight, so this doesn't add any tangible overhead to your application, and it will help make your code more predictable.

Comment: yeah I read the doc before but didn't concentrated as this method is discouraged. I added code in bootstrap.js as in the above updated question :) Now its working, thanks alot..